# Which programming structure for clustering algorithm

Tags: python, data-structures, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to implement the following (divisive) clustering algorithm (below is presented short form of the algorithm, the full description is available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/540963/diana.pdf)):

Start with a sample x, i = 1, ..., n regarded as a single cluster of n data points and a dissimilarity matrix D defined for all pairs of points. Fix a threshold T for deciding whether or not to split a cluster.

1. First determine the distance between all pairs of data points and choose a pair with the largest distance (Dmax) between them.
2. Compare Dmax to T. If Dmax > T then divide single cluster in two by using the selected pair as the first elements in two new clusters. The remaining n - 2 data points are put into one of the two new clusters. x_l is added to the new cluster containing x_i if D(x_i, x_l) < D(x_j, x_l), otherwise is added to new cluster containing x_i.
3. At the second stage, the values D(x_i, x_j) are found within one of two new clusters to find the pair in the cluster with the largest distance Dmax between them. If Dmax < T, the division of the cluster stops and the other cluster is considered. Then the procedure repeats on the clusters generated from this iteration.

Output is a hierarchy of clustered data records. I kindly ask for an advice how to implement the clustering algorithm.

**EDIT 1:** I attach Python function which defines distance (correlation coefficient) and function which finds maximal distance in data matrix.

```
# Read data from GitHub
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nico/collectiveintelligence-book/master/blogdata.txt', sep = '\t', index_col = 0)
data = df.values.tolist()
data = data[1:10]

# Define correlation coefficient as distance of choice
def pearson(v1, v2):
  # Simple sums
  sum1 = sum(v1)
  sum2 = sum(v2)
  # Sums of the squares
  sum1Sq = sum([pow(v, 2) for v in v1])
  sum2Sq = sum([pow(v, 2) for v in v2]) 
  # Sum of the products
  pSum=sum([v1[i] * v2[i] for i in range(len(v1))])
  # Calculate r (Pearson score)
  num = pSum - (sum1 * sum2 / len(v1))
  den = sqrt((sum1Sq - pow(sum1,2) / len(v1)) * (sum2Sq - pow(sum2, 2) / len(v1)))
  if den == 0: return 0
  return num / den


# Find largest distance
dist={}
max_dist = pearson(data[0], data[0])
# Loop over upper triangle of data matrix
for i in range(len(data)):
  for j in range(i + 1, len(data)):
     # Compute distance for each pair
     dist_curr = pearson(data[i], data[j])
     # Store distance in dict
     dist[(i, j)] = dist_curr
     # Store max distance
     if dist_curr > max_dist:
       max_dist = dist_curr
```

**EDIT 2:** Pasted below are functions from Dschoni's answer.

```
# Euclidean distance
def euclidean(x,y):
  x = numpy.array(x)
  y = numpy.array(y) 
  return numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum((x-y)**2))

# Create matrix
def dist_mat(data):
  dist = {}
  for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(data)):
      dist[(i, j)] = euclidean(data[i], data[j])
  return dist


# Returns i & k for max distance
def my_max(dict):
    return max(dict)

# Sort function
list1 = []
list2 = []
def sort (rcd, i, k):
  list1.append(i)
  list2.append(k)
  for j in range(len(rcd)):
    if (euclidean(rcd[j], rcd[i]) < euclidean(rcd[j], rcd[k])):
      list1.append(j)
    else:
      list2.append(j)
```

**EDIT 3:**
When I run the code provided by @Dschoni the algorithm works as expected. Then I modified the `create_distance_list` function so we can compute distance between multivariate data points. I use euclidean distance. For toy example I load `iris` data. I cluster only the first 50 instances of the dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data', header = None, sep = ',')
df = df.drop(4, 1)
df = df[1:50]
data = df.values.tolist()

idl=range(len(data))
dist = create_distance_list(data)
print sort(dist, idl)
```

The result is as follows:

> [[24], [17], [4], [7], [40], [13], [14], [15], [26, 27, 38], [3, 16,
>   39], [25], [42], [18, 20, 45], [43], [1, 2, 11, 46], [12, 37, 41],
>   [5], [21], [22], [10, 23, 28, 29], [6, 34, 48], [0, 8, 33, 36, 44],
>   [31], [32], [19], [30], [35], [9, 47]]

Some data points are still clustered together. I solve this problem by adding small amount of data noise to `actual` dictionary in the `sort` function:

```
# Add small random noise
for key in actual:    
  actual[key] +=  np.random.normal(0, 0.005)
```

Any idea how to solve this problem properly?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to answer the question as asked. Could you expand on what you mean by "programming structure?" If you're referring to data structures, what part of your algorithm needs structures, and what are the requirements for the data structures? If all you want is to repeatedly split a collection of elements without caring about how the data is ultimately represented, an array or linked list might work. Alternatively, you could consider some form of tree (like a binary search tree).

Comment: I just need to repeatedly split the data points. I suspect that an array should be enough. Have you any idea where/how to start?

Comment: do you have a programming language in mind? You have an algorithm, so you just need to convert the steps of the algorithm into some code. I'd say start by writing a function.

Comment: I program in Python, but whichever language should be OK. I just need help with 2. and 3. step.

Comment: Start by writing step 1 in python, and include that in your question. This will make your question more complete and answerable.

Comment: I attach the code from my initial attempts.

Comment: Not an answer but `sum([pow(v, 2) for v in v1])` creates a list first then sums, `sum(pow(v, 2) for v in v1)` is sufficient

Comment: Is your goal having a hierarchy of clusters with 2 data points in each fork?

Comment: @Dschoni yes, that is the goal.

Comment: Some more logic questions: Could you explain step 2 a little bit more? You want to sort the data into subclusters in a way, that the data lies closer to the first element. What if the distance is equal? What if, there is more than one maximum distance?

Let's use euclidean for a sample:

    data=[1,2,2.5,4,5]
    output1=[1,2,2.5] 
    output2=[4,5]
    output1.1=[1]
    output1.2=[2,2.5]

yes? no?

Comment: If distance is equal then we decide by random choice (same if there is more than one maximum distance). Your toy example is plausible.

Comment: You don't have to calculate the distance more than once for each pair. Especially if the calculation is more complex, always work with the distance map. I'm updating my answer below in a few minutes.

Comment: The question is not a programming question, but more an algorithm question: How should data-points be separated, when they have no distance? In my example below the dataset [1,1,1] returns the output [[0,1,2]] BY DESIGN as points with no distance always meet the threshold == 0 constraint. If you want to have an ultimate separation, it's no longer a question of clustering.

Comment: just curious. Are you trying to learn to implement the algorithm or just using the algorithm for your data. If just using, why not try http://scikit-learn.org/stable/ . They have all the clustering algorithms implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A proper working example for the euclidean distance:

```
import numpy as np
#For random number generation


def create_distance_list(l):
'''Create a distance list for every
unique tuple of pairs'''
    dist={}
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for k in range(i+1,len(l)):
            dist[(i,k)]=abs(l[i]-l[k])
    return dist

def maximum(distance_dict):
'''Returns the key of the maximum value if unique
or a random key with the maximum value.'''
    maximum = max(distance_dict.values())
    max_key = [key for key, value in distance_dict.items() if value == maximum]
    if len(max_key)>1:
        random_key = np.random.random_integers(0,len(max_key)-1)
        return (max_key[random_key],)
    else:
        return max_key

def construct_new_dict(distance_dict,index_list):
'''Helper function to create a distance map for a subset
of data points.'''
    new={}
    for i in range(len(index_list)):
        for k in range(i+1,len(index_list)):
            m = index_list[i]
            n = index_list[k]
            new[(m,n)]=distance_dict[(m,n)]
    return new

def sort(distance_dict,idl,threshold=4):
    result=[idl]
    i=0
    try:
        while True:
            if len(result[i])>=2:
            actual=construct_new_dict(dist,result[i]) 
                act_max=maximum(actual)
                if distance_dict[act_max[0]]>threshold:
                    j = act_max[0][0]
                    k = act_max[0][1]
                    result[i].remove(j)
                    result[i].remove(k)
                    l1=[j]
                    l2=[k]
                    for iterr in range(len(result[i])):
                        s = result[i][iterr]
                        if s>j:
                            c1=(j,s)
                        else:
                            c1=(s,j)
                        if s>k:
                            c2=(k,s)
                        else: 
                            c2=(s,k)
                        if actual[c1]<actual[c2]:
                            l1.append(s)
                        else:
                            l2.append(s)
                    result.remove(result[i])
    #What to do if distance is equal?
                    l1.sort()
                    l2.sort()
                    result.append(l1)
                    result.append(l2)
                else:
                    i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
    except:
        return result


#This is the dataset
a = [1,2,2.5,5]
#Giving each entry a unique ID
idl=range(len(a))
dist = create_distance_list(a)
print sort(dist,idl)
```

I wrote the code for readability, there is a lot of stuff that can made faster, more reliable and prettier. This is just to give you an idea of how it can be done.

Comment: I pasted the appropriate functions above. Could you please help me with recursion in the sort function.

Comment: Do you need the clusters in hierachical order? Or just the clusters?

Comment: The result is the indices of the data list in input clustered together. If you need the data values, simply set each value in the index list to the value of the input list.

Comment: Can you let me know if this is, what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I look for. Thanks.

Comment: Also have a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/cluster.html

Comment: I load [iris](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data) dataset. When threshold is enough high, all the data points are in the same (big) cluster. But when I lower the threshold I can't achieve that each data point is in its own cluster. Any idea?

Comment: My only idea so far is, that a lot of distances are equal in real datasets and the above code doesn't know what to do (see my comment in the sort function) so it just sorts points together that doesn't belong in the same cluster. If you set the threshold to 0, every point should ultimately be in its own cluster.

Comment: Maybe we should add "diameter checking step" as described in the 4th paragraph [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/540963/diana.pdf)?

Comment: If you need further help above the questions here, you can more easily contact me via e-mail in my profile.

Comment: Just for further input: A test dataset of 'a = [1,1,1]' seems to have the exact same problem. So maybe the same numbers should be treated as same data points or randomly distributed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87906/discussion-between-dschoni-and-andrej).

Answer (score 1):

> Some data points are still clustered together. I solve this problem by
>   adding small amount of data noise to actual dictionary in the sort
>   function.

`If Dmax > T then divide single cluster in two`

Your description doesn't necessarily creates `n` clusters.
If a cluster has two records which has a distance less than `T`,
they will be clustered together (am I missing something?)