# DIvisive ANAlysis (DIANA) Hierarchical Clustering

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

(This post is continuation of my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111343/which-programming-structure-for-clustering-algorithm) question on divisive hierarchical clustering algorithm.)

The problem is how to implement this algorithm in Python (or any other language).

**Algorithm description**

A divisive clustering proceeds by a series of successive splits. At step 0 all objects are together in a single cluster. At each step a cluster is divided, until at step `n - 1` all data objects are apart (forming `n` clusters, each with a single object).

Each step divides a cluster, let us call it `R` into two clusters `A` and `B`. Initially, `A` equals `R` and `B` is empty. In a first stage, we have to move one object from `A` to `B`. For each object `i` of `A`, we compute the average dissimilarity to all other objects of `A`:

[image]

The object `i'` for which equation above attains its maximal value will be moved, so we put

[image]

In the next stages, we look for other points to move from `A` to `B`. As long as `A` still contains more than one object, we compute

[image]

for each object `i` of `A` and we consider the object `i''` that maximizes this quantity. When the maximal value of the equation above is strictly positive, we move `i''` from `A` to `B` and then look in the new `A` for another object that might be moved. On the other hand, when the maximal value of the difference is negative or 0 we stop the process and the division of `R` into `A` and `B` is completed.

At each step of the divisive algorithm we also have to decide which cluster to split. For this purpose we compute the diameter

[image]

for each cluster `Q` that is available after the previous step, and choose the cluster for which diameter is largest.

My starting code is pasted below. Actually the script returns `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`.

```
# Dissimilarity matrix
dm = [
[ 0, 2, 6, 10, 9],
[ 2, 0, 5,  9, 8],
[ 6, 5, 0,  4, 5],
[10, 9, 4,  0, 3],
[ 9, 8, 5,  3 ,0]]

# Create splinter and remaining group
splinter = []
remaining = range(len(dm))

# Find record ra that has the greatest average distance from the rest of the records
ra = 0
dMax = -999
for i in range(len(dm)):
  dSum = 0
  for j in range(len(dm)):
    if i == j:
      continue
    dSum += dm[i][j]
  if dMax < dSum:
    dMax = dSum
    ra = i

splinter.append(ra)
remaining.remove(ra)

# Check every record in remaining  and moves the record if record is closer to splinter
bChanged = True
while bChanged:
  bChanged = False
  for i in range(len(remaining)):
    d1 = 0.0
    for j in range(len(splinter)):
      d1 += dm[i][j]
    d1 /= float(len(splinter))
    d2 = 0.0
    for k in range(len(remaining)):
      if i == k:
        continue
      d2 += dm[i][k]
    if len(remaining) > 1:
      d2 /= (len(remaining) - 1.0)
    if d1 < d2:
      bChanged = True
      splinter.append(i)
      remaining.remove(i)
      break
```

Comment: So in other words, **you have not yet started**. Then better start writing the actual algorithm...

Comment: Maybe I don't know where to start...

Comment: Try starting with the first step of the algorithm. Starting at the end is harder.

Comment: I updated the code. Maybe now somebody has motivation to look at it.

Comment: why so complicated? put each object into an own cluster and you are done. simple loop, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You have used

1. `remaining.remove(ra)`
2. `remaining.remove(i)`

where both `ra` and `i` are indexes, and `list.remove()` expects an [item](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to delete, not the index. You should use `del remaining[ra]` instead.